# NSString bytes hardcoded

Tags: objective-c

I've got a small asset and wanted to embed the bytes. I've taken the asset, printed out the bytes, then put the bytes in a byte array and load those bytes into a string. Looks like an endian problem. What am I doing wrong here?

BytePrinter.app

```
 const char *helloworldc = "Hello, World!";
 NSString *helloworld = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:helloworldc];
 NSData *data = [helloworld dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSLog(@"%@", [data description]);
```

Output:

```
<48656c6c 6f2c2057 6f726c64 21>
```

ByteImporter.App

```
  const uint32_t bytes[] = {0x48656c6c, 0x6f2c2057, 0x6f726c64, 0x21};
  NSString *helloworld = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:bytes
                                                  length:sizeof(bytes)
                                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSLog(@"%@", helloworld);
```

Output:

```
lleHW ,odlro!
```

Comment: The "output" above is not showing you 4 ints, it's showing you 13 bytes, separated by spaces every 4 bytes in order to make it easier to read.  The presentation is not intended to be converted into ints (and, in fact, the presentation produced by `description` (other than NSString's version) should never be relied on in "production" code, since it can change version-to-version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[data descriptions]` returns per-byte output grouped by 4 bytes.

If you want to hardcode your string use such code:

```
const unsigned char bytes[] = {0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x2c, 0x20, 0x57, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x6c, 0x64, 0x21};
NSString *helloworld2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:bytes
                                                length:sizeof(bytes)
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", helloworld2);
```

My code returns correct string

If you want to optimise something (question: what?) you have to care about endianness and correct your `uint32_t` array accordingly

**UPDATE:**
There is a code that can generate required hardcode array by your NSData:

```
const char *helloworldc = "Hello, World!";
NSString *helloworld = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:helloworldc];
NSData *data = [helloworld dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableString *outStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

unsigned char *ubytes = (unsigned char*)[data bytes];

for (int i = 0; i < [data length]; i++) {
    [outStr appendFormat: @"0x%02x, ", ubytes[i]];
}

NSLog(@"%@", outStr);
```

On output you'll get string like this: `0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x2c, 0x20, 0x57, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x6c, 0x64, 0x21,`, so you'll have to add bracers around it.

Comment: My actual asset is much larger. Is there a quick way to do this conversion? Or do I need to write it myself?

Comment: @estobbart Just don't represent a string like that! Hardcode the string value if you must, but don't torture yourself by trying to do this.

Comment: I'm building a static lib. I've spent money on torture worse than this.

Comment: This creates the data on the stack. If you try to use a string too large your program will likely crash. How about encrypting the string in a resource file and loading that and decrypting it?

Answer (score 4):

Skip the NSString step. Problems like this are likely to keep cropping up because you're fighting the framework on how NSString is meant to be used. NSStrings are for human-readable text, while NSData is for byte sequences. If you want a list of arbitrary bytes that retains byte-for-byte accuracy, just use byte arrays and NSData all the way — that's what they're there for.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the endianness problem indeed. I would use an array of `char` or `unichar` instead.

Comment: @estobbart no, you split the bytes that make up the integers into separate chars.

Answer (score 0):

That's not actually the classic endianness problem, that's because data is printed using 'normal', human-readable output (which, anyway, also connected to endianness).